# Installing minimap on vanilla Emacs gives "Invalid face attribute :foreground nil [xxx times]"

Tags: faces, error, minimap

Installing minimap `package-install [RET] minimap [RET]`

Enabling the minimap-mode `M-x minimap-mode`

And opening `~/.emacs` (or any file that enables minimap by default)

Results in the *Messages* buffer showing an increasing number of errors

```
"Invalid face attribute :foreground nil [xxx times]"
```

The program otherwise appears to work normally.

The `~/.emacs` file is completely empty, and I have tried this with two different vanilla installations, with Emacs 26.1 and 27.1.

I'm quite new to Emacs so I guess I may be doing something wrong but I can't figure out what.
I'd appreciate very much any help.

Comment: Did you contact the author of minimap to report the problem?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that this is a problem with the package? Since I'm new to Emacs, and I'm not sure why this is happening, if it is my fault or not, and how to troubleshoot it, I didn't want to assume that it's a bug. I wouldn't think something like this would be overlooked. Or maybe it's not such an important message, and it's harmless. I don't know, that's why I asked.

Comment: Yes, it is either a bug in minimap because it is setting invalid face attributes, or it is a configuration problem causing it to set invalid face attributes. But even that is a bug in minimap, because if it was configured incorrectly it should have given you a single nice error message rather than a bunch of useless ones.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the clarification! I'll contact the package maintainer.